# how to Debug war file inside tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat

I just started to work on `JSF`. And i followed some steps. At last step i created project configured it. After build the project, eclipse created target folder inside of my jsf project. i moved the war file to webapps folder of `apache tomcat`.

After `localhost:8080/firstJsfApp` it worked successfully.

But when I changed something on this project and it recreates the `.war file`. and I have to move it to tomcat folder again (repeatedly).

Is there anyway to make this easier?

Comment: @outDev  Can you share if there is way to debug the same through intellij.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy your webapp to tomcat directly from Eclipse:

```
1st. Open the "Servers" view in Eclipse, and it will allow you to configure a tomcat instance.
2nd. Add your webapp to the tomcat
```

[image: You should end up with something like this]

Then you can debug and hot deploy any changes to the project.

Comment: Oh, i was too late :)

Comment: @outDev Can you share if there is way to debug the same through intellij?

Comment: @mwKART There is a Tomcat plugin for the IntelliJ ultimate edition. For the community edition you could remote debug external Tomcat instance. But better don't use Tomcat directly, use Spring Boot instead, which has an embedded Tomcat. Both editions can debug Spring Boot applications.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link were you can run tomcat in eclipse: http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html

Comment: Thank you. Maybe stackdev tried to tell same thing. But i think it'snt enough

Comment: I think his explanation is the same as provided by the link I've posted, pls accept his answer as he has posted it first, thx.